# Enterprise Service Bus and BPM

Tags: esb, business-process-management

I am a Java professional. I have a requirement to implement Enterprise Service Bus(ESB). There are quite a few ESB providers are available in the market.I am confusing a bit among those.
Please suggest which one is the best to implement ESB and BPM. I am expecting to have an open source solution with rich documentation and easy to understand with number of examples and scenarios so that we can start from scratch and implement it without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the number of options can be confusing. It's highly depends on your use case and what you're trying to achieve. Without much context, I can only share with you the recent tutorial I wrote around Bonita (A Bpm platform) and Apache Camel (A lightweight ESB): http://community.bonitasoft.com/blog/enhance-your-bonita-applications-apache-camel

In this tutorial, I explain how to trigger new process instances on new incoming emails event.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 has a good option with their Enterprise Integratir. This combines ESB, BPM and related functionality.

Check here for more: http://wso2.com/integration

However this is one of those questions that is purely opinion based.